# Large Vector Outer Product Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I want to compute an outer product of the same vector in Matlab. A representative example would be:

```
x=rand(1e5,1);
sigma=x*x'-spdiags(x,0,length(x),length(x));
```

Is there any obvious way to speed this up? x*x' is a symmetric matrix, but have not figured out a way to help Matlab use that information to speed things up.

EDIT: There is a way to do this with loops but I cannot see the benefit yet:

```
for k=1:length(x)
   sigma(k:length(x),k)=x(k).*x(k:length(x));
end
```

The above might work with a sparse array.

Comment: By the way, why aren't you using `kron(x, x')`?

Comment: I believe that Kron does not support multi-threading. I might be wrong. The only other thing I could think of was bsxfun(@times,x,x').

Comment: MATLAB vector/matrix multiplication should be the fastest, so I think `*` or `bsxfun` is just fine. Using the symmetric attribute of `x*x'` could indeed result in a ×2 speedup, but it won't improve the run time complexity.

Comment: @EitanT In fact running it with Kron is much much slower for me than using the regular `*` and eventually i run out of memory. Unfortunatly with `x` of this size I run out of memory with both methods so I took half the size of `x` to test this.

Comment: What is the size of x?

Comment: Yes, the memory problem is what I am hitting as well, which is why I thought taking advantage of the symmetry would help a bit. I have tried running a looped version of the above to avoid memory issues with little success. See above edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using [`pdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) with custom distance function

```
sigmaCompact = pdist( x(:), @(x, Y) x.*Y );
sigma = squareform(sigmaCompact);
```

up to the special treatment of `sigma( k, k );`

Comment: Shai I am running it as we speak. Will let you know.

Comment: @diplodocuscoffeespot - how did it go?

Comment: I have major memory problems so could not run the full set. It does seems to go faster for smaller vectors. Thanks for tip